# How extension properties syntax would be look like

Tags: c#, .net

If Microsoft would add the feature of "Extension Properties", how the syntax of definition of them would appear? [this is an article on MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/10/05/why-no-extension-properties.aspx) is about extension properties (The feature that has been cut from c# 4.0).

Comment: this isn't a real question

Comment: It is a real one for designers and architects.

Comment: public static int PropertyName ( this ClassToExtend ) { get; set; }

Comment: So you think MSFT was stuck on the interface and that is why we don't yet have this feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pure speculation. As far as I know, even Microsoft doesn't yet know what the syntax would be. They could add a new keyword or something else entirely.

However, looking into this further, this is one possible version of the syntax:

```
public static TimeSpan Minutes[this int i]
{
    get { return new TimeSpan(0, i, 0); }
}
```

Comment: But this is the syntax of the method, and will be ambiguous to the compiler, but a good one

Comment: I see your point. One suggestion I've seen is to instead use square brackets for the argument list (`public static string MyExtensionProperty[this targetClass]`). But in the end I don't know if even Microsoft knows what the syntax would be. They could add a new keyword, or something else altogether.

Comment: This would make it close to indexer definition syntax, but a possible one! thanx very much for interaction.

Comment: @MSakherSawan: After looking around and considering this further, I've updated my answer.